# Electron: Change React component state from main.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I have an Electron app with include (among others) the following files:

- `index.js`
- `browserwindow.html`
- `browserwindow.js` (which get compiled from `browserwindow.jsx`)

`index.js` is the main Electron/Node process that runs when the Electron app is started. `browserwindow.html` is rendered in the `guiWindow`, `browserwindow.js` manages this window. (See the files  below.)

What I want, is to send an ipc message from the main Electron proccess to `browserwindow.js`, which then updates the React component state. But when I use the code in the files below and run the Electron app, the state does not change.

`index.js`

```
const electron = require('electron');
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
const app = electron.app;
const url = require('url');
const ipc = electron.ipcMain;


app.on('ready', function(){

  // Make window
  var guiWindow;

  // Set size and do not immediately show
  guiWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 780,
    show: false
  });

  // Load browserwindow.html in the guiWindow
  guiWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/browserwindow.html');

  // Show the window when the .html file is loaded
  guiWindow.once('ready-to-show', function(){
    guiWindow.show();
  });

  // Send an ipc after 3 seconds
  setInterval(function(){
    guiWindow.webContents.send('message', {msg: 'Hello World!'});
  }, 3000);

});
```

`browserwindow.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- The div that React uses: -->
    <div id="mainInterface"></div>
    <script src="react-0.14.3.js"></script>
    <script src="react-dom-0.14.3.js"></script>
    <script src="browserwindow.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

jsx that gets compiled to `browserwindow.js`

```
var electron = require('electron');
var shell = electron.shell;
var ipc = electron.ipcRenderer;

class MainInterface extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, contect){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      testValue: 'Initial state'
    };
  };

  componentDidMount(){ // When the document is rendered

    ipc.on('message', function(event, data){ // When the message is received...
      console.log('Message received');
      this.setState({testValue: 'It worked!'}); // ... change the state of this React component
    });

  }

  render(){
    return (
      <h1>{ this.state.testValue }</h1>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MainInterface />,
  document.getElementById('mainInterface')
);
```

In the Javascript console, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/<file path to the project on my computer>/testproject/browserwindow.js:20:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:194:7)
```

What can I do to fix this issue?

(For some background, I am making an Electron app that should receives messages over MQTT and update the elements on the screen based on the received message.)

Comment: are you importing `React` into `browserwindow.js` ?

Comment: @JosanIracheta I import it in `browserwindow.html` with `<script src="react-0.14.3.js"></script>` and `<script src="react-dom-0.14.3.js"></script>` before `<script src="browserwindow.js"></script>`.

Comment: comment out `ipc.on('message'...` and see if `this.setState` works outside of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `this` points to the different context than component really is. You need to change your code to

```javascript
componentDidMount() {
    // When the document is rendered.
    const self = this;
    ipc.on('message', function (event, data) {
        // When the message is received...
        console.log('Message received');
        // ... change the state of this React component.
        self.setState({testValue: 'It worked!'});
    });
}
```

Or you may replace `function()` callback by `() => {}` because the first option changes the context of the execution.